# Remove the # from the url when using the skrollr- menu

Tags: html, css, url-rewriting, skrollr

I have a site where I used skrollr and skrollr menu. Before I addded skrollr I was cleaning the url each time a navigation button was pressed. After added Skrollr menu the cleaning of the URL doens't seem to be working. This is the code I have in my js file.

```
 // Click event for any anchor tag that's href starts with #
 $('a[href^="#"]').click(function(event) {

    // calculate height
    var navHeight = $("header").outerHeight();

    // The id of the section we want to go to.
    var id = $(this).attr("href");

    // An offset to push the content down from the top.
    var offset = navHeight;

    // Our scroll target : the top position of the
    // section that has the id referenced by our href.
    var target = $(id).offset().top - offset;

    // The magic...smooth scrollin' goodness.
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:target}, 500);

    //prevent the page from jumping down to our section.
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Again this worked before I added Skrollr-menu. Any idea what abut Skrollr menu is over riding this piece of code?

Thanks!

Comment: Just keep using your code and drop skrollr-menu if it worked for you. skrollr-menu for example supports the back-button.

Comment: Here is the site I'm trying to use it on.. and as you can see it doesn't seem to be working    http://grassrootslandscaping.net/

Comment: "it doesn't seem to be working" what exactly doesn't work? It looks like you're using three different codes for handling the menu. Decide for one.

Comment: I'm using Skrollr menu for tablet and desktop, but I'm destroying skrollr for mobile so I am using the code above for that. By not working I mean the the URLs are not being cleaned up...so I want to be seeing just grassrootslandscaping.net instead of grassrootslandscaping.net#contact...does that make sense?

Comment: Skrollr-menu adds the hash using `pushstate`. There's no way to disable this, unless you stop using it.